# subsubsection description and title not separated

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking

When I have `\subsubsection{sub sub section} Some Contents` and some description for it. I cannot distinguish between the title and description as they appear in the same line.

For instance if I do:

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtecs]{acmsmall}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{ALGORITHM}
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}
\IncMargin{-\parindent}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
This is the first section.
\subsection{Sub Section}
This is the sub section.
\subsubsection{Sub Sub Section}

This is the sub sub section.

\end{document}
```

Then the output is like:

```
*Sub Sub Section*: This is the sub sub section.
```

This is how the acm template works like. I tried with article and it was okay.

What I would like to have is:

```
Sub Sub Section:
  This is the sub sub section.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The `acmsmall` class is meant for submissions to ACM journals. You should stick to their style, if your paper is to be submitted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\subsubsection` in [`acmsmall`](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/) is defined as

```
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{10pt}%
                                 {-.5\baselineskip \@plus -2\p@ \@minus -.2\p@}%
                 {-3.5\p@}{\subsubsectionfont}}
```

If you modify the `-3.5\p@` and make it positive (`3.5\p@`), there is a line break between the title and the following text. The indent is still set at `10pt`, which you might want to change though.

Here's a complete minimal example showing the suggested change:

[image]

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtecs]{acmsmall}
\makeatletter
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{10pt}%
                                 {-.5\baselineskip \@plus -2\p@ \@minus -.2\p@}%
                 {3.5\p@}{\subsubsectionfont}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
This is the first section.
\subsection{Sub Section}
This is the sub section.
\subsubsection{Sub Sub Section}

This is the sub sub section.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks Werner! Just a hint for \documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}: instead of "\subsubsectionfont" you have to write "\@subsubsecfont"